# Customizing new Facebook Page Plugin CSS?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

Is customizing new Facebook Page Plugin CSS even possible? I wan't to remove black border around facebook profile photo. I have tried with jQuery, but without success.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the appearance of Social Plugins in any way (except for the official settings) is not possible and not allowed.

For example:

> 13.4 Don’t obscure or cover elements of social plugins.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/